# Let $\mathcal{U}(a,t) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty)$, when $a, t \in \Bbb R$. Show that the sets $\mathcal{U}(a,t)$ form a basis

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{U}(a,t) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty)$, when $a, t \in \Bbb R$. Show that the sets $\mathcal{U}(a,t)$ form a basis for some topology for $\Bbb R$. Prove also that the obtained space isn't Hausdorff.

To show that sets $\mathcal{U}(a,t)$ forms a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\mathcal{U(a,t)_i\}_{a,t \in \Bbb R}}$ they must cover $\Bbb R$ and for any $U_1, U_2$ I must have $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$ or $U_1 \cap U_2 \in \mathcal{B}$

Take $\mathcal{U}(a,t)$ and $\mathcal{U}(b,d)$ then if $a \ge t$ and $b \ge d$ I get that $$\{a\} \cup [t, \infty) = [t, \infty), \{b\} \cup [d, \infty) = [d, \infty)$$

thus $$\mathcal{U}(a,t) \cap \mathcal{U}(b,d) = [\max\{a,b\}, \infty) \in \mathcal{B}$$

I'm not sure am I going in the right direction here? It seems that I would have to go thorugh all the cases with $a \le t$ and $b \ge d$ etc to show this? For example if $a \ge t$ and $b \le d$, then $$\mathcal{U}(a,t) \cap \mathcal{U}(b,d) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty) \cup [d,\infty)$$ but this doesn't help me alot I would probably need to also consider cases with $t$ and $d$?

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \Bbb R$, then $x \in \mathcal{U}(x,t)$ for any $t$. So that condition is clear.

Suppose that $x \in \mathcal{U}(a,t) \cap \mathcal{U}(b,t')$.

Then $$x \in \mathcal{U}(x,\max(t,t')) \subseteq \mathcal{U}(a,t) \cap \mathcal{U}(b,t')$$ where the inclusion is immediate: if $y \in  \mathcal{U}(x,\max(t,t'))$, then $y=x$ and we already know by assumption that $x \in  \mathcal{U}(a,t) \cap \mathcal{U}(b,t')$, or $y \ge \max(t,t')$ which implies $y \ge t$ so $y \in \mathcal{U}(a,t)$ and $y \ge t'$ and so $y \in \mathcal{U}(b,t')$ too. This shows the second condition too.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$R =\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb R} \mathcal V(0,t).$$

Hence the sets cover $\mathbb R$.

By considering all the cases, you’ll see that the intersection of two elements of the « basis » $\mathcal B$ is an element of $\mathcal B$.

*Note: You made an error  in $\mathcal{U}(a,t) \cap \mathcal{U}(b,d) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty) \cup [d,\infty)$.*